# What might be adding parameters to the URL?

Tags: html

I have a login form with username and password parameters.  During development while refreshing the browser, on a few occasions I have seen my form parameters get put in the URL.  This catches my attention since it's a username and password.

```
For example: http://localhost:8080/ui/?username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx#/login?redirectedFrom=%2Fsomewhere
```

However, I don't recall exactly what I did prior to this, and I am unable to reproduce it.  I've seen it 3 times over a period of weeks.

Any ideas what might be causing the form parameters to be put in the URL?

I'm not sure if any of this is relevant, but I'm using angular with ui-router. The parameters are also parameters to POST, but I don't recall whether I submitted them.  I think (although not sure) each time this has happened it was shortly after my login times out and I am redirected to the login page, which adds a ?redirectedFrom parameter.  I'm using Chrome and it remembers and fills in the username/password inputs.  Chrome developer tools is open.  It might be after restarting the server. A browser refresh was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you submitted the form again.

In login form always use POST action in your form tag, like this:

```
<form action="POST">
```

Don't press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh your page after you submit the form. Click in your URL and enter again in your form page.

Comment: I do not want to specify an action because this is angular (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action)

However, I think the code needs to use ng-submit instead of ng-click based on the information at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit which says "it prevents the default action".

I'm still not sure why I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Based on your answer, I think re-submitting the form caused this.  I hope ng-submit instead of ng-click will prevent it in the future on a re-submit.  However, I'd like to test it but I can't reproduce it.